# Exceptions in constructors

Tags: c++, destructor

Consider the following class:

```
struct A
{
    A(){ std::cout << "A()" << std::endl; throw std::exception(); }
    ~A(){ std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl; }
};

A a;
int main(){ }
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cca6ec2a4a7405b)

The Standard promised that the appropriate deallocation function will be called `N4296::5.3.4/20 [expr.new]`:

> If any part of the object initialization described above78 terminates
>   by throwing an exception, storage has been obtained for the object,
>   and a suitable deallocation function can be found, the deallocation
>   function is called to free the memory in which the object was being
>   constructed,

But what about destructor? In that example it was no called. So, did we get UB?

Comment: The destructor isn´t the same as deallocation. And no, it´s certainly not UB to use exceptions.

Comment: The destructor doesn't run when the constructor throws, but the destructor of each field should be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destructors are called for all successfully initialized objects.

Otherwise there would have had to be default zero-initialization (some overhead) in order to be able to assume anything in a destructor.

The A object whose constructor throws, is not successfully initialized. So its destructor is not executed. However, if it had any class type sub-objects (base class sub-objects, data members) that had been successfully initialized prior to the exception, then destructors would be called for these.

And no, throwing from a constructor is not UB.

On the contrary it's the common way of signalling construction failure, and it ensures that the caller will either have a successfully initialized and presumably useable object, or else (just) an exception.

---

History. Originally C++ didn't have exceptions. Construction failure was then signalled by assigning 0 to `this`. I can't recall how that interacted with allocation, but presumably the same way that an exception now does, namely a guaranteed deallocation. But with this scheme you could only fail construction for dynamically allocated objects…

Comment: So the deallocation function is called just to preevent memory leaks?

Comment: @DmitryBundin: Essentially yes. But you can view object creation as an all-or-nothing *transaction*. In that view the deallocation is just a part of undoing things so that nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Destructors are not same as deallocators. Whenever a variable goes out of scope the object referenced to the variable is deleted. In the problem you have given the object is a global variable, so it will be deleted when the program terminates.

Comment: when the program terminates automatically the object will be deleted.